# Square brackets etc inside \keys of menukeys?

Tags: symbols, menukeys

How can I put special characters like the square brackets into a `keys{}` provided by the `menukeys` package?

I tried it with `\[` and `\]` respectively, but it fails. Unlike for the `|` character there does not seem to be a symbol I can reference by name (see below) that will work inside the `\keys{}` command.

I only list the characters I tried below, but I'm generally interested in how I can approach such a problem when I encounter it.

How can I address my specific problem and what would be the steps to take next time I encounter a similar problem (short of asking here).

---

The characters that I'm interest and found to fail so far (including what I tried):

- `[` as `\[`
- `]` as `\]`

Working in escaped or other form:

- `|` `\textbar` (**not** working: `\vbar`, `\|` and `{\|}`)
- `%` via `\%`
- `&` via `\&`
- `#` via `\#`
- `{` via `\{` and `\textbraceleft`
- `}` via `\}` and `\textbraceright`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands you are looking for are `\lbrack` and `\rbrack`, althought using {[} and {]} also works (as was predicted by **barbara beeton** in [`her comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251152/square-brackets-etc-inside-keys-of-menukeys#comment598599_251154)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}

\menu[,]{\{,\},\%,\#,\lbrack,\rbrack,{[},{]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Useful resources to find commands for symbols:

- [`The Comprehensive Symbol List`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/).
- [`Detexify`](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: thanks, these work. As it turns out, though, even though I was using an old version (2003) of the comprehensive symbol list, it is not included in this list. `\lBrack` is, but `\lbrack` is not. Also, I was naturally looking for bracket and "around" the location where `\textbraceleft` and friends were to be found. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: i didn't try it, but might `{[}` and `{]}` work as well?  (i'm guessing that "unprotected" `[` may be getting interpreted as introducing an option.  if that's the case than braces around `]` wouldn't really be needed, but it's easier to remember if input is handled symmetrically.)

Comment: @0xC0000022L I've updated my answer with another option.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're prediction was corrcet. I've updated my answer. Thanks.